# Is there any way to assign multiple images source at one time

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, image-processing

Is there any way in silverlight to assign multiple images at time to selecting single image and set it's source it will assign to all the images in the wrappanel.

Thanks...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach(Image image in imageWrappanel.Children) {
    image.Source = selectedImage.source;
}
```

Assuming you have a wrappanel named `imageWrappanel` and the selected Image is called `selectedImage`.

Comment: Thank you very much I am very thankful to you bcoz I am waiting a long time...!!!!!!!!!!!